# How do I select all the checkboxes in google spreadsheet with javascript?

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox

The description is simple: I have three checkboxes and the third one must select all the others when selected (and deselect them as well, once it's unchecked). All this must be in a grid, I can't use html or any other language but Google Apps Script.

This is probably a simple task for you, but I'm struggling a lot, both with javascript and english. Anyway here's the code:

```js
function checkboxes() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = range.getSheetId();
  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Title').setWidth(1000).setHeight(100);
  var mygrid = myapp.createGrid(3, 3).setCellPadding(5).setCellSpacing(5);

  //One
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 0, myapp.createLabel('One').setId('One'));
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 1, myapp.createCheckBox().setName('One'));

  //Two
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 0, myapp.createLabel('Two').setId('Two'));
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 1, myapp.createCheckBox().setName('Two'));

  var handler1 = myapp.createClientHandler().forTargets(myapp.getElementById('One')).setValue(true).forTargets(myapp.getElementById('Two')).setValue(true);

  //Last
  mygrid.setWidget(2, 0, myapp.createLabel('Last').setId('Last'));
  mygrid.setWidget(2, 1, myapp.createCheckBox().setName('Last').OnClickHandler(handler1));
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Last time I tried it was not possible to use ClientHandlers validations with with checkboxes. So you have to stick with serverhandlers, which are slower, so you might need to add a little infinity progress gif so the user knows something is being done.

Here's an example of the solution I use:

```js
function mygui() {
  var imgUrl = 'https://f0839004-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/hgabreu/files/ajax-loader.gif';
  //I may remove this image from this url at any time. Host yours in a place you control

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('CheckAll example');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  var boxes = ['Example 1', 'Test', 'Last check'];
  var groupName = 'myCheckBoxes';

  var groupAll = groupName+','+boxes.length;
  var image = app.createImage(imgUrl).setId(groupName+',img').setVisible(false);
  var checkAll = app.createCheckBox("Check All").setId(groupAll).setName(groupAll).addValueChangeHandler(
    app.createServerHandler('checkAll_').addCallbackElement(panel)).addValueChangeHandler(
      app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setVisible(false).forTargets(image).setVisible(true));

  panel.add(checkAll).add(image);
  for( var i in boxes )
    panel.add(app.createCheckBox(boxes[i]).setId(groupName+','+i));

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app.add(panel));
}

function checkAll_(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var p = e.parameter; //just shortening
  var checkState = p[p.source] == 'true';
  var parts = p.source.split(',');
  var groupName = parts[0];
  var size = +parts[1];
  for( var i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    app.getElementById(groupName+','+i).setValue(checkState);
  app.getElementById(groupName+',img').setVisible(false);
  app.getElementById(p.source).setVisible(true);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Henrique, forget my comment, I didn't see that it has to 'uncheck' as well... I deleted my answer .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible workaround with client handler :(tested)

*I personally find it easier and more clear to use variables for widget creation instead of having to get them by id... a few lines of code to write but easier to read ;-)*

```
function checkboxes() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = range.getSheetId();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Title').setWidth(200).setHeight(150);
  var grid = app.createGrid(4, 3).setCellPadding(5).setCellSpacing(5);

  //One
  var one = app.createCheckBox().setName('One');
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('One').setId('One'));
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, one);

  //Two
  var two = app.createCheckBox().setName('Two')
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Two').setId('Two'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, two);

  //three
  var three = app.createCheckBox().setName('Three')
  grid.setWidget(2, 0, app.createLabel('Three').setId('Three'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 1, three);
  //...
  var r1 = app.createRadioButton('radio').setHTML('All');
  var r2 = app.createRadioButton('radio').setHTML('None');
  grid.setWidget(3, 0, r1)
  grid.setWidget(3, 1, r2)

  var Chandler1 = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(one,two,three).setValue(true)
  r1.addClickHandler(Chandler1)
  var Chandler2 = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(one,two,three).setValue(false)
  r2.addClickHandler(Chandler2)
  app.add(grid)
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  doc.show(app)
}
```

**EDIT :** following Henrique's comment (very clever !! thanks) here is a 'full checkBoxes' version that works just fine  ;-)

```
function checkboxes2() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = range.getSheetId();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('checkBoxes test').setWidth(200).setHeight(150);
  var grid = app.createGrid(4, 3).setCellPadding(5).setCellSpacing(5);

  var one = app.createCheckBox().setName('One');
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('One').setId('One'));
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, one);

  var two = app.createCheckBox().setName('Two')
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Two').setId('Two'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, two);

  var allP = app.createVerticalPanel()
  var allA = app.createCheckBox().setName('allA');
  var allB = app.createCheckBox().setName('allB').setVisible(false);
  var allP = app.createVerticalPanel().add(allA).add(allB);
  grid.setWidget(2, 0, app.createLabel('All').setId('all'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 1, allP);

  var ChandlerA = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(one,two,allB).setValue(true).forTargets(allB).setVisible(true).forEventSource().setVisible(false);
  allA.addClickHandler(ChandlerA)
  var ChandlerB = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(one,two,allA).setValue(false).forTargets(allA).setVisible(true).forEventSource().setVisible(false);
  allB.addClickHandler(ChandlerB)
  app.add(grid)
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  doc.show(app)
}
```

Comment: hum... you could have two checkboxes (instead of radiobuttons), but hide 'n show them to pretend it's just one and have all the behavior on the client side. I tested it here and it works great!

Comment: Thanks for the idea Henrique ! I just didn't imagine using the 'invisibility trick' ;-) I should read Harry Potter more often (he he)  I added your suggestion in a new version .

Answer (score 0):

Today I finally had the time to see your code, thanks for your support.

Like you said in your comment, I don't need the image at all, so I'm trying to take it out from the function mygui, let's see if I can do it:

```
function mygui() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('CheckAll example');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  var boxes = ['Example 1', 'Test', 'Last check'];
  var groupName = 'myCheckBoxes';

  var groupAll = groupName+','+boxes.length;
  var checkAll = app.createCheckBox("Check All").setId(groupAll).setName(groupAll).addValueChangeHandler(
    app.createServerHandler('checkAll_').addCallbackElement(panel));

  panel.add(checkAll);
  for( var i in boxes )
    panel.add(app.createCheckBox(boxes[i]).setId(groupName+','+i));

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app.add(panel));
}
```

I have just cancelled line nr 2, 3 and 8 then I truncked line nr 9 and 10. That's enough for un unexpected mistake, standing to the error message.

Comment: Are you the same user that asked the question? Why are you not using the same account? Use the same account and then edit your question, making it better. Posting follow ups as answers is not the way to go here on stackoverflow. This is not a mailing list.