# Toggling visibility of widgets with a checkbox on the client?

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script

I am attempting to use a checkbox to toggle visibility of certain widgets. However I'm really struggling to get client side handlers to toggle them correctly.

Here's my best attempt

EDIT: Fully reproducible example

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var checkbox = app.createCheckBox("Toggle Visiblity").setName("togglebox").setId("togglebox");
  app.add(checkbox);
  var listBox = app.createListBox(true)
    .addItem("Item #1")
    .addItem("Item #2")
    .addItem("Item #3")
    .setVisible(false);
  app.add(listBox);

   checkbox.addValueChangeHandler(app.createClientHandler()
                                        .validateMatches(checkbox, "on")
                                        .forTargets(listBox)
                                        .setVisible(true));
  checkbox.addValueChangeHandler(app.createClientHandler()
                                        .validateMatches(checkbox, "off")
                                        .forTargets(listBox)
                                        .setVisible(false));

  return app;
}
```

Theoretically it should work but when I toggle the checkbox nothing happens. I've tried several different values with and without the "i" flag, none of which have worked.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this, *without* using server side handlers?

Comment: have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466249/how-do-i-select-all-the-checkboxes-in-google-spreadsheet-with-javascript/11567639#11567639) I think it answers your question, just replave the setValue(true/false) with setVisible(true/false) in the targets. look at my last edit

Comment: @Sergeinsas Changing the setVisible to setValue didn't work (they were already setVisible). Note that the targets are actually a ListBox and a Label, and that if I remove the validate line it still shows them, I just can't unshow them

Comment: could you post a testable code please ? not just the handler but the whole UI

Comment: thanks, sorry  I was away ;-)

Comment: there it is, tested and working

Comment: also, the link you provided is a dev link that is only useable from your own account so I'm afraid it's kind of useless to put it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working using the 'invisibility trick' that Henrique suggested [in a former post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466249/how-do-i-select-all-the-checkboxes-in-google-spreadsheet-with-javascript/11567639#11567639)

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var checkbox = app.createCheckBox("Toggle Visiblity").setName("togglebox").setId("togglebox").setValue(true);
  var checkbox2 = app.createCheckBox("Toggle Visiblity").setVisible(false);
  var hpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  hpanel.add(checkbox).add(checkbox2);
  app.add(hpanel);
  var listBox = app.createListBox(true)
    .addItem("Item #1")
    .addItem("Item #2")
    .addItem("Item #3")
    .setVisible(false);
  app.add(listBox);

 var ChandlerA = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(listBox).setVisible(false)
 .forTargets(checkbox2).setVisible(true).setValue(false)
 .forEventSource().setVisible(false);
  checkbox.addClickHandler(ChandlerA)
 var ChandlerB = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(listBox).setVisible(true)
 .forTargets(checkbox).setVisible(true).setValue(true)
 .forEventSource().setVisible(false);
  checkbox2.addClickHandler(ChandlerB)

  listBox.setVisible(true);
return app
  }
```

Edit : note that the last statement `listBox.setVisible(true)` is not logical to my opinion but if I omit it the listBox is not visible before clicking... I don't really understand that... anyone knows ?

EDIT2 : Ooooops how silly I am, I didn't notice the `setVisible(false)` you added when creating the listBox ;-P hum hum... really stupid from me ... I guess You wanted to start 'invisible' ? in this case there will be some minor changes to bring to this code... 
like this (I finally decided to show both versions...)

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var checkbox = app.createCheckBox("Toggle Visiblity").setName("togglebox").setId("togglebox").setVisible(false);
  var checkbox2 = app.createCheckBox("Toggle Visiblity").setVisible(true).setValue(false);
  var hpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  hpanel.add(checkbox).add(checkbox2);
  app.add(hpanel);
  var listBox = app.createListBox(true)
    .addItem("Item #1")
    .addItem("Item #2")
    .addItem("Item #3")
    .setVisible(false);
  app.add(listBox);

 var ChandlerA = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(listBox).setVisible(false)
 .forTargets(checkbox2).setVisible(true).setValue(false)
 .forEventSource().setVisible(false);
  checkbox.addClickHandler(ChandlerA)
 var ChandlerB = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(listBox).setVisible(true)
 .forTargets(checkbox).setVisible(true).setValue(true)
 .forEventSource().setVisible(false);
  checkbox2.addClickHandler(ChandlerB)

return app
}
```

Comment: thanks ;-) I slightly changed the first version because forTargets() is chainable ... Could you check the "answered box" (ha ha !)